# Remove white rectangles KivyMD MDExpansionPanel

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to make a GUI with kivy and kivymd but I encountered a problem. The documentations say that the icon of an MDExpansionPanel default to "". But when I type `icon=""` in the `MDExpansionPanel(content_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(text=str(i)), icon="")` I still get white rectangles that are in front of the text. Could someone help me out please?

**My (reduced) .py file:**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel, MDExpansionPanelOneLine
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

KV="""
Screen1:
    id: screen1
    FloatLayout:
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Run"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':0.8}
            on_press: root.panel()
        RecycleView:
            key_viewclass: 'viewclass'
            key_size: 'height'
            pos_hint: {'top':0.7}
            size_hint: [1,.6]
            do_scroll_y: True
            BoxLayout:
                id: box
                orientation: "vertical"
"""


class Screen1(MDScreen):

    def panel(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            self.ids.box.add_widget(MDExpansionPanel(panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(text=str(i))))

class ExampleApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(KV)

ExampleApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Update KivyMD library from master branch.